# Declare variables and increase that inside Django templates

Tags: python, django

I want to declare a  variables inside Django templates and increase that by one .

my code is

```
{% with 0 as my_variable %}
   {% for address in user.addresses %}
       {{my_variable=my_variable+1}}
       {% if my_variable==1 %}
           // do something
       {% else %}
           // do something
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

It's giving the error of

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: can't assign to 'const'

How to declare the variable and increase it?

Comment: What you should use is `forloop.counter`, which supports starting index both 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What you want is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

```py
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ forloop.counter }} {# starting index 1 #}
    {{ forloop.counter0 }} {# starting index 0 #}
    {# do your stuff #}
{% endfor %}
```

```py
{{ forloop.counter }}  {# The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed) #} 
{{ forloop.counter0 }} {# The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed) #}
```

Also keep in mind

```py
{{ forloop.first }} {# True if this is the first time through the loop #}
```

and

```py
{{ forloop.last }}  {# True if this is the last time through the loop #}
```